# Is rails reporting its own action as deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, attachment-fu

Sorry if it is a dumb question, but the issue is quite straight forward. If I do,

```
$ rails new testproj
$ cd testporj
$ rails plugin install git://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu.git
```

Which should just create a empty proj and install attachment_fu in it. But then, trying to start it up:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and conf
ig/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails
-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at c:/Users/fgadotti/rails/apps/blobtest/testproj/confi
g/environment.rb:5)
Exiting
```

The heck? What did I miss?
It is rails 3.2.2 on windows I have installed.

thanks,

Comment: attachment_fu is not well supported on rails 3. Use carrierwave

Comment: seriously? well.. these were some wasted hours.. -_-

Comment: @DanS Oh, an by the way, carrierwave doesn't seem to be able to use DB as storage, does it? Any other plugin recommendation that would do it?

Comment: yeah, but heroku won't agree then :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plugin install` will be deprecated in rails 4.

Gems are now preferred, which are added to `Gemfile` in your application's root directory and installed with `bundle install`

attachment_fu is not very well supported with rails 3, I'd use carrierwave instead. You can use Rmagick's [to_blob](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#to_blob) method to store the images in the database.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. The actual problem I am dealing with is a little broader than storing images though. I've asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093171/store-unknown-type-of-data-in-the-database-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

like the error suggests there is a new rails version needed:

make sure you add your gemfile to the newest version and run

```
rake rails:update
```

this is one thing also the warning suggest you need to move your dependencies out of vendors and put them in your gemfile then run:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: right.. but, shouldn't the whole thing be consistent? I mean, shouldn't this version of rails be coherent with its own standards? (I mean, in what refers to `plugin install` needing to be fixed right after being installed)